# amsrefs with bibtex -- using the webpage type

Tags: bibtex, amsrefs

I'm using amsrefs together with a .bib file to handle my references, and I would like to cite a webpage (say https://tex.stackexchange.com/ for an MWE).

**My question**: is there a way to enter a webpage into my references.bib file so that amsrefs knows to assign it to the type `webpage' in the .bbl?

In an ideal world, one would just add

```
@webpage{TexSE,
  TITLE={Tex StackExchange},
  AUTHOR={The Community},
  URL={https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
}
```

to the file references.bib, and then in the main tex file have

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}
    \cite{TexSE}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

However, on compilation this creates the following .bbl:

```
% \bib, bibdiv, biblist are defined by the amsrefs package.
\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib{TexSE}{}{
      author={Community, The},
       title={Tex stackexchange},
         url={https://tex.stackexchange.com/},
}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
```

In particular I get an error because the bib item is not of a valid type (in fact not of any type).

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I've forwarded this to a member of the AMS support team for consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use `misc` (or any other supported type) for anything else you can use `misc` then alias it to webpage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\BibSpecAlias{misc}{webpage}

\begin{document}
    \cite{TexSE}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

with a bib file

```
@misc{TexSE,
  TITLE={Tex StackExchange},
  AUTHOR={The Community},
  URL={https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
}
```